# React/ReduxForm: Is there a validation within redux form to validate for duplicate names?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Is there a way to check if the user entered in the same "name" twice. Similar to a check you see for usernames and passwords. I'm using redux-form.

Comment: Can you add more information? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an async validation to check on your backend if you have the same name on database.

Check the example: https://redux-form.com/8.2.0/examples/asyncvalidation/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to validate your case is backend validation.